# AS3 htmlText is showing tags

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, htmltext

I have a textfield created with AS3 as thus: (theDesc is a parameter passed through a function)

```
var productDescTxt:TextField = new TextField();
productDescTxt.htmlText = theDesc;  
productDescTxt.multiline = true;
productDescTxt.wordWrap = true;
productDescTxt.embedFonts = true;
productDescTxt.setTextFormat(productInfoTF);
productDescTxt.x = 10;
productDescTxt.y = productNameTxt.y+productNameTxt.textHeight+15;
productDescTxt.width = 325;
holder.productsTab.addChild(productDescTxt);
```

`theDesc` is html content with character encodings:

ex:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;6.1 oz cotton at an affordable price&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

the problem is the textField is displaying every character. `<p><strong>` etc.

Is there any extra encoding need done on my end?

Comment: What does theDesc look like where your setting it?

Comment: It's being passed as a String exactly like my example.

Comment: like this &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;6.1 oz cotton at an affordable price&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;?

Comment: yes. character for character like my example.

Comment: So why don't you do the html_decode in a server side language or type it directly into xml or string?

Answer (score 0):

view source of this page and find this line:

**<weare the something>**

this answer box does almost the same as flash textField htmlText function.
more about htmlText posibilieties in flash: [TextField – available html tags](http://gasubasu.com/2009/07/06/textfield-%E2%80%93-available-html-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get it from some server, don't you? You need to change `&lt;` with `<`, `&gt;` with `>` manually. E.g. in PHP (if server part of your app is written on PHP) there's `html_decode()` function which will replace all for you. I don't know of similar function in AS3.

But, I can advise you small trick:

```
var tempField:TextField = new TextField();
tempField.htmlText = theDesc;  
var productDescTxt:TextField = new TextField();
//...
productDescTx.htmlText = tempField.text;  
holder.productsTab.addChild(productDescTxt);
```

that will do `html_decode()` for you! hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want HTML special characters for the htmlText value, escape them see this answer [Unescape (decode) HTML characters from string in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308757/unescape-decode-html-characters-from-string-in-flex)