# Unescape (decode) HTML characters from string in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How can I unescape HTML encoded characters (such as `&gt;`, `&lt;`, etc.) from a string, in Flex (AS3)?

So, I have a string `"x &gt; 3"` and I want the result string as `"x > 3"`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to just send it through a TextArea or other text based component.  This will also strip off containing CDATA tags,